# Vimscripts: check if item in list

Tags: vimscript

I was wondering how to check if an element is in a list. I have the following function defined in a file:

```
let g:some_list = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]

function! Test(item)
    if a:item in g:some_list
        echo "Yes"
    else
        echo "No"
    endif
endfunction
```

After sourcing the file I called the function with `:call Test("a")`. It shows the following error:

```
Error detected while processing function Test:
line    1:
E15: Invalid expression: a:item in g:some_list
```

So in regard to the invalid expression, the question is how do I check if an item is in a list? Couldn't find anything in `:help if`, `:help list`.

Comment: If you do `:h list` and then scroll down until you see `List functions` (or go directly to `:h Dictionary` and scroll a page up). Also Please see `:h list-functions` and `:h function-list`

Comment: `if count(g:some_list, a:item) > 0` works. Not sure if this is best way.

Answer (score 10):

`index()` can be used to check whether or not an item is in a list.

The body of your function should be written like this:

```
if index(g:some_list, a:item) >= 0  " If item is in the list.
    echo "Yes"
else
    echo "No"
endif
```

To check that the item is not in the list, use `index(g:some_list, a:item) == -1` instead.

Answer (score 9):

I think that `index()` would be the most efficient way for a strict equality. There is `match()` when pattern matching is required IIRC.

As Christian said, `:h list-functions` is a perfect place to start. Still many list related functions are missing. Over the years I've defined the one I'm missing in my library plugin: https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/list.vim

Note that since then, some functions now exist -- but we can not assume they exist for each version of Vim :(